# cakephp 3.0 plugin routing not working

Tags: cakephp, plugins, url-routing, cakephp-3.0

I have below code in app_root_directory\plugins\Business\config\routes.php
when i add below route to this file, it does not work

```
Router::plugin( 'Business', ['path' => '/' ], function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect(
            '/:state/localities', ['controller' => 'Cities', 'action' => 'localities', 'plugin' => 'Business' ], [
        'state' => '[0-9a-z-]+', 'pass' => ['state' ] ]
    );

    $routes->fallbacks( 'InflectedRoute' );
} );
```

I'm accessing http://example.com/ab/localities
when route is added to app_root_directory\config\routes.php , it works why that ?

```
Router::scope( '/', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect(
            '/:state/localities', ['controller' => 'Cities', 'action' => 'localities', 'plugin' => 'Business' ], [
        'state' => '[0-9a-z-]+', 'pass' => ['state' ] ]
    );

    $routes->fallbacks( 'InflectedRoute' );
} );
```

Comment: my app installed on root http://example.com/qc/:state/localities works this way, but not http://example.com/:state/localities

Comment: It'll be matching another route then. You need to show your routes, and indicate _what actually happens_.